# Python Error Exit Status 1 for Anaconda/Jupyter

Tags: python, error-handling, geopandas

I am trying to pip install geopandas and keep getting an exit 1 status error. Then I try to pip install GDAL, but still get the same error. I can pip install other libraries just fine, so don't know where this is coming from. Any ideas?

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for gdal
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\ Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ \AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oe6w8_hs\\gdal_c05dbd958e124d1a91f8d136cee3c342\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ \AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oe6w8_hs\\gdal_c05dbd958e124d1a91f8d136cee3c342\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-b95x1co9\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\ Anaconda3\Include\gdal'
         cwd: C:\Users\ AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oe6w8_hs\gdal_c05dbd958e124d1a91f8d136cee3c342\

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\ Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ \AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oe6w8_hs\\gdal_c05dbd958e124d1a91f8d136cee3c342\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ \AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oe6w8_hs\\gdal_c05dbd958e124d1a91f8d136cee3c342\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-b95x1co9\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\ Anaconda3\Include\gdal' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Forgot to add: A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have installed anaconda, I would recommend following instructions from the geopandas project: https://geopandas.org/getting_started/install.html

From my experience, setting up a work environment with conda-forge repositories as a default sets a very convenient context for working with geopandas.